# Creating MySQL Events In Workbench EER Diagram

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL's EER Diagram builder to construct the design of my database, I understand it's possible to create routine groups and create procedures and functions inside them, but it this possible with scheduled Events as well? I tried creating an Event inside a routine group but it kept saying I had a syntax error even though the Event's syntax was actually correct when I created it through a query tab. Can events only be created through the query command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, events are currently not supported in MySQL Workbench's GUI (it's on our TODO list for a while however). You can of course write SQL code and execute that, which contains event statements, but the GUI is not able to work with them (no object editor, no support in modeling).